# Web API 2 services - how to return an Exception message in the Status

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible, in Web API 2 to directly return the Exception message in the response's Status ?

For example, if I was writing a WCF Service (rather than Webi API), I could follow [this tutorial](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page2.htm) to directly return an Exception message as part of the response status:

[image]

Here, the web service doesn't return any data in the Response, and the error message gets returned directly in the Status Description.

This is exactly what I'd like my Web API services to do when an exception occurs, but I can't work out how to do it.

Most suggestions suggest using code like below, but then the error message will then always get returned in a separate response string, rather than being part of the Status.

For example, if I were to use this code:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllProducts()
{
    try
    {
        //  Let's get our service to throw an Exception 
        throw new Exception("Something went wrong");

        return Ok(products);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult(
            Request.CreateErrorResponse((HttpStatusCode)500, 
                new HttpError("Something went wrong")));
    }
}
```

... then it returns a generic 500 message, and the exception is returned in a JSON string.

[image]

Does anyone know how to modify a Web API function (which returns an `IHttpActionResult` object) to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could register a custom global filter that will handle all Exceptions. Something like:

```
public class CatchAllExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message)
        };
    }
}
```

You will need to register it in WebApiConfig.cs, with:

```
config.Filters.Add(new CatchAllExceptionFilterAttribute());
```

This filter will be hit everytime there is an unhandled exception in the system and set the http response to the exception message. You could also check the different types of exception and alter your response accordingly, for example:

```
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if(context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Method not implemented.")
            };
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message)
            };
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling
Please refer above link, it will help you!